# Failed to load resources when trying to perform syntax highlighting in a blog

Tags: blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I used [syntax highlighter](https://code.google.com/archive/p/syntaxhighlighter/) in my blog, but seems like now it can't find the relevant resources. I followed [this tutorial](http://heisencoder.net/2009/01/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-blogger.html) to add that functionality to the blog by editing the template.

```
<!-- Add-in CSS for syntax highlighting -->  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushDelphi.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushPhp.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushRuby.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushVb.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
<script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

These above resources are failing to load.

Any reason for that, How can i fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The project is gone.
2. Google code is gone (http://google-opensource.blogspot.de/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html)

But there is help: [This](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter) might be the project you are looking for.

Comment: yeah, you are right. this has a way to overcome that. 
http://janbernhardt.blogspot.com/2014/08/enabling-code-syntax-highlighting-for.html